# How do I bootstrap building the jdk?

Tags: java, linux, openjdk-11

I am attempting to build `jdk-11+8` in order to read the generated source of `java.nio.ByteBuffer` for Linux.

I installed all the dependencies based on the [documentation](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/raw-file/tip/doc/building.html#common-make-targets), and then successfully ran `configure`.

However, when I run `make`, I get a strange error about a missing Java package, which looks like a bootstrapping problem.

```
git clone https://github.com/openjdk/jdk.git 
pushd jdk
bash configure
...
The existing configuration has been successfully updated in
/home/ubuntu/Code/jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release
using default settings.

Configuration summary:
* Debug level:    release
* HS debug level: product
* JDK variant:    normal
* JVM variants:   server
* OpenJDK target: OS: linux, CPU architecture: x86, address length: 64
* Version string: 11-internal+0-adhoc.ubuntu.jdk (11-internal)

Tools summary:
* Boot JDK:       openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)  (at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64)
* Toolchain:      gcc (GNU Compiler Collection)
* C Compiler:     Version 8.4.0 (at /usr/bin/gcc)
* C++ Compiler:   Version 8.4.0 (at /usr/bin/g++)

Build performance summary:
* Cores to use:   4
* Memory limit:   15854 MB

make clean
make

Building target 'default (exploded-image)' in configuration 'linux-x86_64-normal-server-release'
Warning: No mercurial configuration present and no .src-rev
Compiling 117 files for BUILD_java.compiler.interim
/home/ubuntu/Code/jdk/src/java.compiler/share/classes/javax/annotation/processing/Messager.java:28: error: package javax.annotation does not exist
import javax.annotation.*;
^
1 error
CompileInterimLangtools.gmk:86: recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/Code/jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/buildtools/interim_langtools_modules/java.compiler.interim/_the.BUILD_java.compiler.interim_batch' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/ubuntu/Code/jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/buildtools/interim_langtools_modules/java.compiler.interim/_the.BUILD_java.compiler.interim_batch] Error 1
make/Main.gmk:76: recipe for target 'interim-langtools' failed
make[2]: *** [interim-langtools] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

**What am I missing?**

More system details:

```
ubuntu@box:~$ uname -a
Linux box 4.15.0-1057-aws #59-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 10:02:00 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu@box:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS \n \l
```

Digging a little more, I also see the following error, which may or may not be relevant:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-40-153:~/Code/jdk$ make -n gensrc > /tmp/X
make[3]: *** No rule to make target '/home/ubuntu/Code/jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/buildtools/jdk_tools_classes/_the.BUILD_TOOLS_JDK_batch', needed by '/home/ubuntu/Code/jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/support/gensrc/java.logging/_the.COMPILE_PROPERTIES.marker'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [java.logging-gensrc-src] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** No rule to make target '/home/ubuntu/Code/jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/buildtools/jdk_tools_classes/_the.BUILD_TOOLS_JDK_batch', needed by '/home/ubuntu/Code/jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/support/gensrc/jdk.charsets/sun/nio/cs/ext/_the.charsetmapping-extcs'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [jdk.charsets-gensrc-src] Error 2
make[3]: *** No rule to make target '/home/ubuntu/Code/jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/buildtools/jdk_tools_classes/_the.BUILD_TOOLS_JDK_batch', needed by '/home/ubuntu/Code/jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-release/support/gensrc/java.base/sun/util/cldr/CLDRBaseLocaleDataMetaInfo.java'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [java.base-gensrc-src] Error 2
vmake[1]: *** [main] Error 2
make: *** [gensrc] Error 2
```

Comment: Two easy things to test: a different boot JDK (say, the latest update of JDK10), and a different build-target (you are using `default`, but [other, more specific targets](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/doc/building.md#running-make) are available

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried `gensrc` which is the target I actually cared about, but it gave the same error as the default target. I'll try a different boot jdk.

Comment: Looks like with JDK 10 instead of JDK 11 as boot JDK, it's making more progress!

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that I was using JDK 11 as the boot JDK, and this was not working because the `javax.annotations` package was [removed](https://blogs.perficient.com/2019/05/15/the-java-commons-annotations-was-removed-in-jdk-11/) from JDK 11.

Downgrading to jdk 10 manually and pointing `configure` at it fixed the problem for me.

```
wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk10/10.0.2/19aef61b38124481863b1413dce1855f/13/openjdk-10.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
tar xf openjdk-10.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

bash configure --with-boot-jdk=/home/ubuntu/Code/jdk10/jdk-10.0.2
make
```

Since `jdk 10` is deprecated, I had to pull the link from the [archive](https://jdk.java.net/archive/).